# Google Sheets - Search Each Cell In A Range and Past to Another Column if Number

Tags: google-apps-script

I am a complete novice to Google Sheets and looking for some help on what I THINK will be a pretty easy script? I can write it in VBA and it works like a charm, but I have no idea how to translate that to Google Sheets, or how to trigger it...

On my Google Sheet, on the Duplicate Registrations tab, I have a list of Invoice Numbers between I7 and I152. These cells can only have three possible values - a 13-digit number, a hyphen (-), or it can be blank. These cells are being populated by a VLOOKUP to my calculations tab, which is in turn pulling its data from half a dozen other tabs.

**All I need the script to do is look at each cell between I7 and I152. If the value is a number, copy/paste value that number into Column B on the same Row. If it is a Hyphen or if it is blank, ignore it and move on to the next.**

If it helps, this is how I would do it in MS Excel:...

```
Dim r As Integer
For r = 7 To 152
If Cells(r, "I") > 0 Then
    If Cells(r, "I") <> "-" Then
        Range("I" & r).Select
          Selection.Copy
          Range("B" & r).Select
          Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
              :=False, Transpose:=False
    End If
End If
Next
```

I also have a question about how to trigger the script. Does Google Sheets allow you to add a button, or does it have to be a CTRL-ALT-SHIFT-# shortcut?

Thank you in advance!! I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this figured out!  :)  Posting the solution, just in case someone comes across this at some point down the road looking the same thing:

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var range = sheet.getRange("I7:I152");
  var values = range.getValues();

  Logger.log(values);

  row_index = 7; 

  values.forEach(function(i_column_value) {

    Logger.log(row_index, i_column_value);

    if (i_column_value != "") {
      sheet.getRange('B' + row_index).setValue(i_column_value);
    }
    row_index++;

  });
```